# Ray ray = head.Gaze.What does this do?

Tags: unity-game-engine

What does this line of code do ? Im hoping it would cast a ray to where the head gazes.Im doing this so that 
Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition); here i can cast a ray to where the head gazes rather than the mouse position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ray is a vector with a starting position and a direction. In the case of:

```
Ray ray = head.Gaze;
```

you are getting the direction in which the user is looking and the starting point. It is most likely the same as getting the camera forward and its position at once.

```
Ray ray = new Ray();
ray.direction = Camera.main.transform.forward;
ray.origin = Camera.main.transform.position;
```

EDIT: Based on comment

In order to check for collision you would use Raycast:

```
Raycasthit hitInfo;
float distance = 10.0f;
if(Physics.Raycast(ray.origin, ray.direction, out hitInfo, distance)){}
```

Comment: so if i want to cast a ray , from the camera to the world,say 10units and get the collider's transform .Is that possible ? Can you show me an example ? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you can use a Raycast().
here is an example:

```
Ray ray = new Ray(Camera.main.transform.position, Camera.main.transform.forward);
RaycastHit hit;

if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 10))
{
    // test what the raycast hit by checking hit information.
}
```

This will cast a ray from the main camera's position, looking forward (directly in front) at a max distance of 10 units and will output hit information in the hit variable that you can then test things from.

Edit: 
Since you do not provide any additional information other than the head.Gaze i can not tell you what it does, but assuming it was named correctly, it would do the same thing as the *Ray(Camera.main.transform.position, Camera.main.transform.forward);* so you can instead write the raycast test like so:

```
RaycastHit hit;
if (Physics.Raycast(head.Gaze, out hit, 10))
{
    // test what the raycast hit by checking hit information.
}
```

We would need to know what the head object is and what is the object type of Gaze. If it is a Ray, i am 99.9% sure it will act as a ray for the look forward direction from your head. You can always test this :)